# using character array as a key in map

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, stl

I am trying to use `char[]` as a *key* for a `map`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<utility>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    map<char[10],int> m;

    char c[10]={'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'};
    m[c]=78;
    return 0;
}
```

But is throwing an error:

> error: array used as initializer
>
> second(std::forward<_Args2>(std::get<_Indexes2>(__tuple2))...)

even this doesn't work: `m["abcdefghi"]=4;`

How to use `char []` as a key? I have couple of questions on SO but they didn't help much.

**NOTE:** I have used `string` but I want to try `char[]` just for curiosity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays have neither the copy constructor nor the copy assignment operator. And there is no default operator < for arrays.

Instead of array use the standard container `std::array`.

For example

```
#include<iostream>
#include <array>
#include<map>

int main()
{
    std::map< std::array<char, 10>, int> m;

    std::array<char, 10> c = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'};
    m[c]=78;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you are absolutely right, **strict weak ordering** (`<`) is required condition for the `key` which is not possible in `char[]`.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus That part isn't a big problem. You could provide a comparator solving that: `template<typename T>
struct less {
    using type = typename std::remove_extent_t<T>;
    static constexpr size_t extent = std::extent_v<T>;

    constexpr bool operator()(const type (&a)[extent],
                              const type (&b)[extent]) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(std::begin(a), std::end(a),
                                            std::begin(b), std::end(b));
    }
};`

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int
main()
{
  using key_type = std::array<char, 10>;
  std::map<key_type, int> m;

  key_type c{ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
  m[c] = 78;
}
```

---

If you want variable size, use `std::string_view`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string_view>

int
main()
{
  std::map<std::string_view, int> m;

  char c[10] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0' };
  m[{c, sizeof(c)}] = 78;
}
```